# What's in include/uapi of kernel source project

Tags: networking, kernel

Can someone please give me a document to describe the kernel source folders about their structure, functionality and how they are organized?

Specifically, what's the use of of the folder include/uapi/**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The `uapi` folder is supposed to contain the user space API of the kernel.  Then upon kernel installation, the uapi include files become the top level /usr/include/linux/ files. (I'm not entirely clear on what exceptions remain.)

The other headers in theory are then private to the kernel. This allow clean separation of the user-visible and kernel-only structures which previously were intermingled in a single header file.

The best discussion I have seen of this is [located at a Linux Weekly News](http://lwn.net/Articles/507794/) article that predates the patch landing.

The UAPI patch itself landed with kernel 3.7.  Linus's [quick and dirty summary](http://lwn.net/Articles/519762/) is:

> - the "uapi" include file cleanups. The idea is that the stuff
>     exported to user space should now be found under include/uapi and
>     arch/$(ARCH)/include/uapi.
>
>   Let's hope it actually works. Because otherwise this was just a
>     totally pointless pain in the *ss. And regardless, I'm definitely done
>     with these kinds of "let's do massive cleanup of the include files"
>     forever.

Comment: Great pointers! Though the summary is not that dirty in my view of Linus ;-p